# Difference between setTimeout(fn,0) vs setTimeout(fn,1)

Tags: javascript, webapi, event-loop

I have this bit of code:

```js
setTimeout(
  () => console.log("setTimeout callback is complete"),
  0);

fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping")
  .then(() => console.log("fetch callback is complete"));

// busy-wait for a few seconds:
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
  }
}

console.log("busy-wait is complete");
```

I was expecting this output:

```
busy-wait is complete
fetch callback is complete
setTimeout callback is complete
```

because microtasks (such as promise outputs) have higher priority than macrotasks (such as setTimeout timers); but when I try it in Chrome, I actually get this output:

```
busy-wait is complete
setTimeout callback is complete
fetch callback is complete
```

(Note: I'm expecting the `fetch` call to be pretty quick; it should finish before the busy-wait is complete.)

When I increase setTimeout's timer duration to 1 ms, it outputs what I expected.

```js
setTimeout(
  () => console.log("setTimeout callback is complete"),
  1); // <--- this is the change

fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/ping")
  .then(() => console.log("fetch callback is complete"));

// busy-wait for a few seconds:
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
  }
}

console.log("busy-wait is complete");
```

My question is, what's changed after I increase the setTimeout duration, even to just 1 ms? Why does it evaluate the two situations differently, and ignore the fetch priority when the timer duration is 0 ms?

Comment: You realize `fetch` is getting data outside your computer right? It can take any amount of time depending on your network...

Comment: @ChrisHamilton correct but I'm sure that I already got response from fetch when javascript execution is completed. Basically I have 2 timer and 1 fetch promise needs be fired after console.log("Queue 3").

Comment: Ah I see, with my limited knowledge of the event loop, I would guess browsers might push a zero setTimeout to the queue immediately when called, but if it is more than zero, it will first execute other code before deciding what tasks to push to the queue. ie. the first one pushes the setTimeout tasks before the for loop, the second one pushes them on after and prioritizes the fetch call accordingly.

Comment: Check your network tab in developer tools to see how much time fetch is taking, it's not immediate. It take quite a few ms.

Answer (score 2):

> because microtasks (such as promise outputs) have higher priority than macrotasks (such as setTimeout timers);

No, they don't have higher **priority**. They are not part of the task prioritization system at all. Once a [microtask is queued](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-microtask), it will get executed at the next [microtask checkpoint](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#perform-a-microtask-checkpoint), which is generally when the current JS script ends execution as part of [clean after running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script).
So even between two callbacks that are not tasks<sup>1</sup> like two `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks fired in the same animation frame, queued microtasks will get executed.

However, [`fetch()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) will actually [queue a *fetch task*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-queue-a-fetch-task%E2%91%A5)<sup>1</sup> that will itself [resolve](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#resolve) the `Promise` it returned. So the microtask associated with the `Promise` resolution will actually get queued from that *fetch task*.

And that's where the prioritization system comes in. At the end of your busy loop we have in the [timer task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-task-source) our `setTimeout` task, and in the [networking task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#networking-task-source), our fetch task.
With this, we can't assume anything about the order in which these two tasks will get executed. The specs let the user agent decide whatever they deem is best with the step 2.1 of the [event loop processing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop):

> Let *taskQueue* be one such [task queue](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue), chosen in an [implementation-defined manner](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#implementation-defined).

Browsers do use many heuristics to choose between the various task queues, and while it's generally agreed that UI tasks will get higher priority than others, between network and timer it's a lot less clear. Also given that Chrome only recently [removed a 1ms clamping](https://crbug.com/402694) to their `setTimeout()` implementation, I wouldn't even consider the current behavior as being *stable*, they may very well decide to deprioritize even 0ms timers at some point in the future, and they'd still be specs compliant.

If one wants to queue tasks with a given priority, then there is an incoming [Prioritized `postTask` API](https://github.com/WICG/scheduling-apis/blob/main/explainers/prioritized-post-task.md) that does that, but it's still not widely supported (Chrome has it unflagged, Firefox had a weird implementation at some point, and I'm not sure Safari really followed there just yet).

<sup>1. Note that "m**a**crotask" isn't a thing, there are only "tasks" and "m**i**crotasks".</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> microtasks (such as promise outputs) have higher priority than macrotasks (such as setTimeout timers)

Correct. You can verify that like this:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("macrotask (setTimeout)"), 0)
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("microtask (promise)"))
console.log("sync")
```

Output:

```plain
sync
microtask (promise)
macrotask (setTimeout)
```

However, what you're doing is not just queueing an immediately resolved promise, but rather sending a `fetch` request. The *request* is sent immediately as a microtask, but the *response* arrives back after `setTimeout` completes.

Comment: That is very strange output for the code shown (I would expect only the text in the console.log statements in the output)...

Comment: Yep, typo. Fixed now.